# Why private method does not became overwritten

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute code from official php docs, but I can not understand why private `Bar` method does not became overwritten by `Foo`?

```
class Bar 
{
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }

    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test();
```

Prints `Bar::testPrivate Foo::testPublic`, but why?

Comment: You cannot overwrite private methods, use `protected` for this purpose

Comment: Please add "PHP" in to the question title to help people easily find your question. Also please change "overwritten" to "overridden" as it's a well-known OOP term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment from the same documentation you are probbaly using

> If you have problems with overriding private methods in extended
>   classes, read this:)
>
> The manual says that "Private limits visibility only to the class that
>   defines the item". That means extended children classes do not see the
>   private methods of parent class and vice versa also.
>
> As a result, parents and children can have different implementations
>   of the "same" private methods, depending on where you call them (e.g.
>   parent or child class instance). Why? Because private methods are
>   visible only for the class that defines them and the child class does
>   not see the parent's private methods. If the child doesn't see the
>   parent's private methods, the child can't override them. Scopes are
>   different. In other words -- each class has a private set of private
>   variables that no-one else has access to.
>
> A sample demonstrating the percularities of private methods when
>   extending classes:

```
<?php  abstract class base { 
     public function inherited() { 
         $this->overridden(); 
     } 
     private function overridden() { 
         echo 'base'; 
     }  } 

 class child extends base { 
     private function overridden() { 
         echo 'child'; 
     }  } 

 $test = new child();  $test->inherited();  ?>
```

> Output will be "base".
>
> If you want the inherited methods to use overridden functionality in
>   extended classes but public sounds too loose, use protected. That's
>   what it is for:)
>
> A sample that works as intended:

```
<?php  abstract class base { 
     public function inherited() { 
         $this->overridden(); 
     } 
     protected function overridden() { 
         echo 'base'; 
     }  } 

 class child extends base { 
     protected function overridden() { 
         echo 'child'; 
     }  } 

 $test = new child();  $test->inherited();  ?>  Output will be "child".
```

See [Php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#87413) for the original comment

Answer (score 0):

In PHP only `public` and `protected` method could be overwritten.Not `private` ones.